# VS2015 CodedUI Remote test distribution - Unit Test Adapter threw exception

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, coded-ui-tests

**What I want to achieve** 
I have a CodedUI automation project, when I run the tests from within VS I want the tests to be deployed to a bunch of physical test machines that I have set up which are running test agents. My project includes packages installed through nuget. I.e Oracle ManagedDataAccess

**What I have currently have working** 
I have a test controller installed on my local machine and test agents installed on other physical machines. Within my Visual Studio project I have added the .testsettings file to my solution and the agents are successfully connecting to my controller.

I have tested the connections between the controller and agents by creating a new coded ui project, recorded a simple test (open IE) and ran the test successfully remotely.

**My problem** 
As soon as I add any packages to the solution i.e OracleManagedDataAccess and attempted to run the test I receive an exception of type:
" Unit Test Adapter threw exception: 
Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.."

Could someone please explain the cause of this exception and help me in resolving it?

Thanks 
Tim